# Как запарсить нужный класс если он дублируется. Python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт с погодой, хочу запарсить определенный класс, но их несколько.
Как обратиться к нужному?

Вот что у меня сейчас:

```py
for temp in soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'unit unit_temperature_c'):
    temp = temp.text
```

Вот сам сайт:

```html
<div class="now-weather">
  <span class="unit unit_temperature_c">
    <span class="sign">**−**</span>
    **"3"**
  </span>

  <div class="now-feel">**По ощущению**>
    <span class="unit unit_temperature_c">
      <span class="sign">**−**</span>
      ***6***
    </span>
```

Comment: Можно использовать `xpath` или в цикле обратиться к нужному, например `span_text = temp.find('span').text`

Comment: Можно обратиться по позиции в списке: `soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'unit unit_temperature_c')[0].text`

Comment: Ещё можно поступить так, у Вас различаются классы div, находим нужный и досоём текст: `t = soup.find('div', 'now-feel').find('span', 'unit unit_temperature_c').text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классов `unit_temperature_c` несколько, но у каждого есть тег выше с особенным классом: `now-weather` и `now-feel`

Пример:

```
...

print(
    soup.select_one('.now-weather > .unit_temperature_c').get_text(strip=True)
)
# **−****"3"**

print(
    soup.select_one('.now-feel > .unit_temperature_c').get_text(strip=True)
)
# **−*****6***
```

---

**PS.**

Метод `select_one` с css-селектором через `find` можно так повторить:

```
print(
    soup.find(class_='now-weather').find(class_='unit_temperature_c').get_text(strip=True)
)
# **−****"3"**
```

Comment: А если и now-weather и now-feel тоже больше одного?

Comment: @ADDDoN, 2 варианта: 1) запрашивать списком и по индексам брать, либо в css-селекторе использовать обращение по индексу через http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child, подправив `select_one` ) 2) либо посмотреть какие еще есть уникальные теги или атрибуты у них самих или у их тегов выше